# easeljs rotating a shape around its center - gets offset

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

Can anyone explain why, when both rectangles are placed in the same position, the red triangle jumps to an offset before rotating around its center?

```
//Create a stage by getting a reference to the canvas
stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
//Create a Shape DisplayObject.
rect1 = new createjs.Shape();
rect1.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
rect1.regX = rect1.regY = 20;  //rotate around center
rect1.alpha = .3;

rect2 = new createjs.Shape();
rect2.graphics.beginFill("green").drawRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
rect2.alpha = .3;
// place rectangles in the same position
rect1.x = rect1.y = rect2.x = rect2.y = 100;

//Add Shape instance to stage display list.
stage.addChild(rect1,rect2);

createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", onTick);

function onTick() {
    rect1.rotation++;
    stage.update();
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3au1dx92/)

What regX, regY values need to be provided to keep it in place overlaying the green?

(The 2013 answer provided did not show the original position)

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: You have to play a bit around by changing variables and deduce how it works. You can't solve it by setting the right regX and regY value but you have to change the starting position of the rectangles

Answer (score 1):

That's supposed to happen; work around it by adding the regX/regY values to the position of the rotating rect. `rect1.x = rect1.y = 120; rect2.x = rect2.y = 100;`